# Loop back to the beginning

Tags: python-3.x

How can I loop back to the beginning, when my player hit one of the white squares? I have tried to loop, but I don’t know where I can set the while loop, to restart the game from Scratch. Loop back, and start to move from the beginning. In other words, restart the game.

```
import turtle
import math

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("blue")
wn.tracer(3)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("red")
player.shape("circle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(-225, 50)

square = turtle.Turtle()
square.color("white")
square.shape("square")
square.penup()
square.speed(0)
square.setposition(-200, 100)

square_2 = turtle.Turtle()
square_2.color("white")
square_2.shape("square")
square_2.penup()
square_2.speed(0)
square_2.setposition(-250, 50)

speed = 0.4

def turnleft():
    player.left(90)

def turnright():
    player.right(90)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(turnleft, "Left")
turtle.onkey(turnright, "Right")

while True:
    player.forward(speed)

    d = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor()-square.xcor(),2) + math.pow(player.ycor()-square.ycor(),2))
    if d < 20:
        square.q()

    d = math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor()-square_2.xcor(),2) + math.pow(player.ycor()-square_2.ycor(),2))
    if d < 20:
       square_2.q()
```

Comment: What is the `.q()` method meant to do?

Comment: The ```.q()``` is there, because I decided to quit the program. Cause I didn’t figured out, how I could loop back to the beginning, and start over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the code to initialise the player and the squares in a separate method, you can simply call that when you need.

I don't really use Python, so the following code probably has many beginner mistakes, but it works:

```
import turtle
import math
from time import sleep

wn = 0
player = turtle.Turtle()
square1 = turtle.Turtle()
square2 = turtle.Turtle()

speed = 1

def init():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("blue")
    wn.tracer(3)
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(turnLeft, "Left")
    turtle.onkey(turnRight, "Right")

def initCharacters():
    player.color("red")
    player.shape("circle")
    player.penup()
    player.speed(0)
    player.setposition(25, 20)
    
    square1.color("white")
    square1.shape("square")
    square1.penup()
    square1.speed(0)
    square1.setposition(100, 100)

    square2.color("yellow")
    square2.shape("square")
    square2.penup()
    square2.speed(0)
    square2.setposition(150, 50)
    
def distanceIsLessThan(p, q, distance):
    return math.pow(p.xcor() - q.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(p.ycor() - q.ycor(), 2) < math.pow(distance, 2)
    
def turnLeft():
    player.left(90)

def turnRight():
    player.right(90)

def main():
    init()
    initCharacters()
    
    while True:
        player.forward(speed)

        if distanceIsLessThan(player, square1, 20) or \
           distanceIsLessThan(player, square2, 20):
            # print("Touch")
            initCharacters()

        sleep(0.02)
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(I had to change the speed and positions and put in a sleep while I was getting it to work.)